# AWS object invalidation- / How to be Sure If Image removed from Edge

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I want to invalidate root directory and from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#invalidation-specifying-objects

It says we can use wild cards

Let's say we have path like

https://cdn_url/rootimage/first/1/type/1.png

https://cdn_url/rootimage/first/1/type/2.png

https://cdn_url/rootimage/first/2/type/1.png

https://cdn_url/rootimage/first/2/type/2.png

https://cdn_url/rootimage/second/1/type/1.png

https://cdn_url/rootimage/second/1/type/2.png

https://cdn_url/rootimage/second/2/type/1.png

https://cdn_url/rootimage/second/1/type/2.png

So If I write

```
 AmazonCloudFrontClient objClient = new AmazonCloudFrontClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["s3accesskey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["s3secret"]);
        objClient.CreateInvalidation(new CreateInvalidationRequest
        {
            DistributionId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CDNDistributionId"],
            InvalidationBatch = new InvalidationBatch 
            { 
                Paths = new Paths { Items = "/cdn_url/rootimage/*", Quantity = 1 } 
            }
        });
```

Will the above code work.
and what about Quantity will it be 1 or count of all actual images.

How can I validate that invalidation is complete.

I also tried manually on portal, after few minutes I saw it is saying invalidation is complete,How Can I be sure If Image is removed from Edge.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lots of digging It seems,

Image Header response can be used

> Connection
>   keep-alive
>   Date
>   Mon, 15 Feb 2016 09:54:40 GMT
>   Etag
>   "8239143f88d513feb78b025c5d4e1da7"
>   Last-Modified
>   Fri, 12 Feb 2016 05:32:30 GMT
>   Server
>   AmazonS3
>   Via 
>   1.1 cldfrontUrl.ddfds (CloudFront)
>   X-Amz-Cf-Id 
>   NKGtNTaLYGepIJ9Vjc1xgtQGn4AuhukYutQBDtSRPIyTGBDwLcxXgA==
>   X-Cache 
>   **Miss from cloudfront**

So If it is

> Miss from cloudfront  // Object is not in edge..

and

> Hit from cloudfront  //Object is in edge..

Answer (score 2):

The invalidation path needs to be relative to the path in the CloudFront URL used to access what you want to invalidate -- not relative to the back-end (origin server) URL/path.

To invalidate all the content in a distribution (i.e. everything, starting at the root) the correct path to specify is simply `*`.   Using `/*` will also work.

Comment: Yes thank.. It means If provide like root/* it will delete all images inside sub folder of root too..

Comment: Correct.  Also, the `Quantity` is set to 1, because you are only requesting 1 *pattern* be evaluated.  The number of files is not important.

Comment: Unfortunately for /root/* is not removing all files under subdirectories.

Comment: I also manually did invalidation in aws with full path, but still I am able to see the image..